# In Numpy, how can I index an B x N x M array with a size B array of indices to yield a B x M array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to index the 2nd axis of a `BxNxM` array (the `N` axis) with `B` indices and get a `BxM` array as the result.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Say the `BxNxM` array is called `A`, then the desired output is `A[(np.arange(B), indices)]`.